# Network singleton with retrofit in android - null reference exception

Tags: android

I have following singleton

```
public class APIShared {

    public String API_BASE_URL = "http://url.com/";
    public static APIShared instance;
    public APIManager client;

    private Context context;
    private Retrofit retrofit;

    private APIShared (Context context) {

        this.context = context;

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        client = retrofit.create(APIManager.class);

    }

    public static APIShared init(Context context){

        if (null == instance){
            instance = new APIShared(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

and in my `MainActivity` inside `onCreate` I call

```
Call<List<Category>> call = APIShared.instance.client.categories();
```

And when I start app I get

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.example.me.fooder.APIManager com.example.me.fooder.APIShared.client' on a null object reference

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're screwing up the singleton pattern.  Instance should be private static.  init() is generally named getInstance (although that's not required) and is the only way to access instance.  Your call would look like:  APIShared.init().client.categories();